# Bootstrap Vue Navar issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-4

When I add the navbar to my code it does not respect the Bootstrap style. I mean, I look this menu to the left without any margin and If I use ml-auto mx-auto to set the menu to the left or right it does not work so I wonder what am I doing wrong.

Thanks

```
<template>
<div>
    <b-navbar toggleable="lg" type="light" variant="">
        <b-navbar-brand href="#">
            <img :src="'logo.png'" height="80" alt="Site Logo" />
        </b-navbar-brand>

        <b-navbar-toggle target="nav-collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>

        <b-collapse id="nav-collapse" is-nav>
            <b-navbar-nav>
                <b-nav-item href="#">Inicio</b-nav-item>
                <b-nav-item href="#">Quiénes Somos</b-nav-item>
                <b-nav-item href="#">Nuestras Iniciativas</b-nav-item>
                <b-nav-item href="#">Transparencia</b-nav-item>
                <b-nav-item href="#">Contacto</b-nav-item>
                <b-nav-item href="#">Blog</b-nav-item>
                <b-nav-item href="#">Preguntas Frecuentes</b-nav-item>
            </b-navbar-nav>
            <!-- Right aligned nav items -->
            <b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto">
            
                <b-navbar-nav>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i></a>
                </b-navbar-nav>
                
            </b-navbar-nav>
        </b-collapse>
    </b-navbar>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version and whatever library uses the `b-` syntax. I assume it's BootstrapVue, but you need to state that.